# Label versus value in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to create a mapping from bond ratings "AAA, AA+, AA, AA-, ... " to a numerical equivalent "-29, -28, -27, -26, ... "

I want the cell's value to differ from the label. For example, I would like a cell with the label AAA to have an underlying value of -29. This would enable me to use the excel filtering to select rows with bond ratings > [threshold]. The numerical equivalent / mapping provides me a means of doing so.

Is this value/label distinction a possibility in Excel? If not, what are some of my options if I wish to apply filtering via my own custom ranking?

Comment: I think your best bet would be to add a separate column for the numeric values, and use vlookup() to populate it.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally go with Tim William's solution of using a VLookup, because it's the easiest one. 
Or, when using VBA, by loading the separate columns in a bidimensional array and retrieving the "label" by setting a conditional statement when looping through the array.

Just in attempt to answer your question, you can give cell (or ranges) a "name", which is litterally why they are being called "Named Ranges".
*Theoretically* you could give a cell a value of -29, and retrieve the name of the range based on its value. 
Note that Named Ranges only allow letters, numbers (don't start with a number) and underscores, so you would need to use a name such as "AA_PLUS" or "AA_MINUS". 
Imagine that you add the name "AA" to cell(1,1) in sheet(1) of the workbook, you retrieve the named range:

```
dim sName as string

sName = thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells(1,1).name.name
debug.print sName
```

After sorting the values, the names are still correctly retrieved and you can load them into an array if wished. 
Although the benefit is that you don't need to reserve sheet space for adding an extra column and it increases flexibility (named ranges can be placed anywhere since the name sticks to the cell), I wouldn't recommend this approach when you're working with an enormous amount of data.

Generally they are being used in the opposite direction as the way I explained just now. 
First you define a name for a range, than you retrieve its value and not the other way around (although there is no rule that forbids it and the code is available). 
Named ranges offer flexibility and are often a must to make a tool dynamic. I mean this in the sense that ranges can be moved around while the VBA will still correctly retrieve their value(s).

Well, and another "label type solution" would be to add comments to each cell (of which the content can be set and get programatically), but again I have never used this approach and for long data structures I wouldn't recommend it.

```
sName = thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells(1,1).comment.text
```